# Go: zlib uncompressing a slice of bytes

Tags: go

I am trying to parse a file that annoying consists of many separately zipped segments. I have parsed these segments one at a time into a slice of bytes and I want to uncompress them as I go.

Here is my current code that does the decompressing, which doesn't work. `from` and `to` are just set at the top as an example, in reality they are set by the code. `data` is the byte array containing the entire file. I don't want to seek it while it's on disk because its location on another server, so it's only realistic for me to load the entire file to []byte first and then parse it.

```
from, to := 0, 1000;
b := bytes.NewReader(data[from:from+to])
z, err := zlib.NewReader(b)
CheckErr(err)
defer z.Close()
p := make([]byte,0,1024)
z.Read(p)
fmt.Println(string(p))
```

So how is it so massively difficult just to unzip a slice of bytes? Anyway...

The problem appears to with how I am reading it out. Where it says z.Read, that doesn't seem to do anything.

How can I read the entire thing in one go into a slice of bytes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an outline for you. Note: In Go, CHECK FOR ERRORS!

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "compress/zlib"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func readSegment(data []byte, from, to int) ([]byte, error) {
    b := bytes.NewReader(data[from : from+to])
    z, err := zlib.NewReader(b)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer z.Close()
    p, err := ioutil.ReadAll(z)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return p, nil
}

func main() {
    from, to := 0, 1000
    data := make([]byte, from+to)
    // ** parse input segments into data **
    p, err := readSegment(data, from, to)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(p))
}
```

Comment: you checked for errors one time to much... :-) in main()

Answer (score 3):

Use `ReadAll(r io.Reader) ([]byte, error)` from the `io/ioutil` package.

```
p, err := ioutil.ReadAll(b)

fmt.Println(string(p))
```

[Read](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) only reads up to the length of the given slice (1024 bytes in your case).

To read in chunks of 1024 bytes:

```
 p := make([]byte,1024)

 for {
   numBytes, err := l.Read(p)
   if err == io.EOF {
      // you are done, numBytes might be less than len(p)
      break
   }
   // do what you want with p
 }
```

If you are getting the data from a webserver, you might even do

```
 import (
   "net/http"
   "io/ioutil"
 )
 ...
 resp, errGet := http.Get("http://example.com/somefile")
 // do error handling
 z, errZ := zlib.NewReader(resp.Body)
 // do error handling
 resp.Body.Close()
 p, err := ioutil.ReadAll(b)
 // do error handling
```

since resp.Body happens to be an io.Reader as most io related types.